# Memory limit exceeded with the use of a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, memory-limit

This line of code creates an error message "Memory limit exceeded" when length is 100,000 and I don't quite understand why.

```
int[][] multiply = new int[length][length];
```

Comment: *`java -Xmx40G` should be enough for everyone* - Bill Gates ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You try to make an array of 100,000 * 100,000 entries of probably 4 bytes each.
That is 40,000,000,000 bytes, around 40GB. Even if you have that kind of memory installed, the system will probably enforce some limits long before that.